# A problem of trigonometry (high school)

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, soft-question, education

> In a quadrilateral $ABCD$ are known $\overline{AB}=6a'\sqrt3$, $\overline{AD}=15a'\sqrt2$ and the angles $D\hat{C}A=\pi/4$, $A\hat{B}C=2\pi/3$, $A\hat{C}B=\pi/6$. Calculate the measure of the diagonal $AC$ and the perimeter of the quadrilateral.

The solutions of my textbook are: $\overline{AC}=18a'$ and the perimeter is $2p=(12\sqrt 3+36\sqrt 2)a'$.

I put the original Italian question:

[image]

*My synthetic solution*: I have drawn the image:

[image]

We have:

$$\frac{b}{\sin \beta}=\frac{c}{\sin \gamma} \implies b=18 a', \quad \frac{a}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{b}{\sin \beta} \implies a=6a'\sqrt 3$$

Hence $c=a=6a'\sqrt 3$. I know that $\eta=\pi/3$ and $\delta=\pi/4$. Thus $\psi=5\pi/12=15°$. Now

$$\frac{15a'\sqrt 2}{\sin \delta}=\frac{\overline{DC}}{\sin \psi} \implies \overline{DC}=30a'\cdot \sin(15°)$$
and
$$\sin(15°)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(\pi/6)}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt 6 -\sqrt 2}{4}$$

**Possibly I will have made some mistake or there is an error in the textbook of an high school but I will never find that perimeter of the solution.**

Lastly, my female student has forwarded me her solution

[image]

and she asks me how her could derive from the arcosine $\text{arcsin}=\sin^{-1}$ a non-approximate relation to derive the correct misure of the angle when it is:

$$\sin^{-1}\left(\frac 35\right)$$

(see the red rectangles).

Comment: My dear Sabastiano, the data are problematic: you wrote both $\widehat{DCA}=\dfrac\pi 4$ and  $\widehat{DCA}=\dfrac{2\pi}3$ ??

Comment: @Bernard Very kind Bernard thank you...I am very tired. First I wrote it in pen and then I converted it to mathjax. Now I edit the wrong data. Thanks a lot for the warning....

Comment: However, I must say that I first had read $\widehat{ABC}=\frac{2\pi}3$, and could conclude that triangle $ABC$ was isosceles, and could conclude that indeed $AC=18a'$ using Al Kashi's formula.

Comment: @Bernard I have deleted the wrong data...but you have 3 up-comment (there is also the mine) :-). I have never known "Al Kashi's formula" :-(

Comment: Neither did I  under that name when I was in high-school. It is the formula  $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos\hat{A}$, and similar for the other sides of a triangle.

Comment: @Bernard Ah the Carnot's theorem. In the my draft I have also used the "Al Kashi's formula" but I, after, have changed my way. :-)

Comment: Didn't know the name of Carnot for this result (yet  a French name!)

Comment: @Bernard See this :-) https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_del_coseno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your mistake: $\eta \ne \pi/3$

$\displaystyle \frac{AD}{\sin \delta} = \frac{b}{\sin \eta} \implies \sin \eta = \frac{3}{5}$ and so $\displaystyle \cos \eta = \frac{4}{5}$

Now, $\displaystyle \sin \psi = \sin (\pi - ({\eta + \frac{\pi}{4}})) = \sin (\eta + \frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (\sin \eta + \cos \eta) = \frac{7}{5 \sqrt2}$

So using $\displaystyle \frac{CD}{\sin \psi} = \frac{AD}{\sin \delta}$, $CD = 21 \sqrt2 a'$.

As you know all sides, adding them leads to perimeter of
$(12 \sqrt3 + 36 \sqrt2) a'$.

Comment: Very kind but $\eta+\beta=\pi$? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano that is not correct. It is not a cyclic quadrilateral. Only in cyclic quadrilaterals, opposite angles add to $\pi$.

Comment: I have not understood the concept of "cyclic quadrilaterals" :-( When can I write that $\eta+\beta=\pi$? thank you again.

Comment: If the quadrilateral had $\eta + \beta = \pi$, you would be able to draw a circle that passes through all its vertices. That is called cyclic quadrilateral. In this case, calculation clearly shows that $\eta \ne \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Please read "Supplementary Angles" in wiki link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral

Comment: I have read before the italian version here: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilatero_ciclico#:~:text=In%20geometria%2C%20un%20quadrilatero%20ciclico,uguale%20all'angolo%20interno%20opposto. :-)

Comment: Hence being $(\alpha+\psi)+(\delta+\gamma)\neq \pi$ implies also that $\eta+\beta\neq \pi$ hence I have not a  cyclic quadrilateral?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\beta=\frac{2\pi}3$ and $\gamma=\frac\pi6$ we deduce that the triangle $ABC$ is isosceles so
$$
\overline{AC}=2 \overline{AB}\cos\frac\pi6=18a.
$$
Correspondingly from the cosine law:
$$
\overline{AD}^2=\overline{AC}^2+\overline{DC}^2-2\overline{AC}\cdot\overline{DC}\cdot\cos\frac\pi4,
$$
which positive solution is $\overline{DC}=21\sqrt2\,a$.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. In my notes done with my hand I have written: $\overline{DC}=(15a'\sqrt 2)^2+(18a')^2-215a'\sqrt2 18a \cos \psi$. But then I abandoned the path. What do you think my student did wrong? With my heart on my sleeve I am very tired and can't find the mistake. She uses approximate angles and I reported to her not to approximate anything. Could you please complete your answer with the rest of the question kindly? Thank you very much first of all.

Comment: Actually I did not yet take a look at this sheet of paper, but I really do not understand the claim: $$\sin\gamma=\frac{AC}{AD}\sin\frac\pi6.$$ Neither $\gamma$, nor $\frac\pi6$ seem to have a relation to the triangle $ACD$.